# How to remove everything after the last number in a string

Tags: python, regex

I have strings like this:

```
w = 'w123 o456 t789-- --'
```

My goal is to remove everything after the last number, so my desired output would be

```
w123 o456 t789
```

It is not always the same ending, so `-- --` is just one example.

```
import re

re.sub('(.*?)(\d)', '', w)
```

gives me

```
'-- --'
```

How can I modify the command so that it removes this part?

Comment: If you use greedy dot, you will get your value with `re.sub('(.*\d).*', r'\1', w)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Seems to work as well. Feel free to add it as an answer then I would upvote it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use:

```
>>> w = 'w123 o456 t789-- --'
>>> re.sub(r'\D+$', '', w)
'w123 o456 t789'
```

`\D+$` will remove 1 or more non-digit characters before end anchor `$`.

Comment: One might also want to consider using `[^0-9]` rather than `\D`, because that requires less knowledge of REs to use.

Answer (score 2):

The point is that your expression contains *lazy* dot matching pattern and it matches up to and including the first one or more digits.

You need to use *greedy* dot matching pattern to match up to the *last* digit, and capture that part into a capturing group. Then, use a `r'\1'` backreference in the replacement pattern to restore  the value in the result.

This will work with 1-line strings:

```
re.sub(r'(.*\d).*', r'\1', w)
```

or with anchors and also supporting strings with linebreaks:

```
re.sub(r'^(.*\d).*$', r'\1', w, flags=re.S)
```

[Python demo:](https://ideone.com/hX5aTY)

```
import re
w = 'w123 o456 t789-- --'
print(re.sub(r'^(.*\d).*$', r'\1', w, flags=re.S))
# => w123 o456 t789
```

Answer (score -2):

```
st = 'w123 o456 t789-- --'
print st.rstrip()
"w123 o456 t789'
```