# How to remove everything (except certain characters) after the last number in a string

Tags: python, regex

This is a follow-up of [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39637955/how-to-remove-everything-after-the-last-number-in-a-string)

There I learned how to remove all characters after the last number in a string; so I can turn

```
w = 'w123 o456 t789-- --'
```

into

```
w123 o456 t789
```

Now I might have strings like this:

```
w = 'w123 o456 (t789)'
```

In this case,

```
re.sub(r'\D+$', '', w)
```

would give me

```
w123 o456 (t789
```

So I have then actually two closely related questions:

1) How can I modify the command `re.sub(r'\D+$', '', w)` in a way that certain characters are kept (e.g. parenthesis)?

2) How can I modify the command `re.sub(r'\D+$', '', w)` so that only certain characters are removed (e.g. dashes and white spaces)?

**EDIT**

@Martin Bonner's answer gets very close but e.g. for

```
w='w123 -o456 t789--) --'
```

the command

```
 re.sub('[- ]+$', '', w)
```

gives me `w123 -o456 t789--)` but it should also get rid of the remaining dashes.

Comment: @MooingRawr: How would I use those? Could you give an example?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use another re.sub in the callback as the replacement pattern.

```
re.sub(r'\D+$', lambda m: re.sub(r'[^()]+','',m.group(0)), s)
```

Here, you match all  symbols other than digits at the end of the string, pass that value to the callback, and all symbols other than `(` and `)` are removed from that value.

Comment: Great! That works fine, even for the rather pathological case in the edit! (upvoted).

Comment: I believe it to be a generic solution to your problem. The price is two regex replacements. Do not forget to compile the regex objects if you want to use this approach.

Answer (score 4):

To keep certain characters `(` and `)` use:

```
re.sub('[^0-9()]+$', '', w)
```

to remove only certain characters from the end of the line:

```
re.sub('[- ]+$', '', w)
```

In square brackets, you can list the characters you want to match.  If the first character is `^` then everything *except* the specified characters are matched.  The only minor niggle is that `-` usually specifies a range (so we can specify, eg, all digits without having to list all 10 of 
them).  That means that if we are going to specify `-` as one of the characters to match, it needs to go *first*.  (If you want to specify `^`, then escape it with `\` and go back to raw strings.)

From the comment, I think you actually meant the second challenge to be
"remove all the dashes and spaces from the string that lie between the last digit, and the end of the line".  That may be possible with a regular expression, but somebody who comes back to maintain the code in three months time will hate you (and it may well be you).  Just remember the Jamie Zawinski quote:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions.”  Now they have two problems.

Comment: Seems to work fine, thanks (upvoted)! One more question: Where do you specify that you want to remove things after the last digit in `re.sub('[- ]+$', '', w)`. Where do you look for a digit?

Comment: For example for `w='w123 -o456 t789--) --'` I get `w123 -o456 t789--)`, the other two dashes remain but should also be removed.

Comment: My second RE will remove trailing dashes and spaces.  Dashes after the last digit and before the `)` are not trailing dashes.  If you want to do something more complex, you can either learn about programming regular expressions, or write out the algorithm you want to implement in code.

Comment: Ok, yes for all cases I deal with, your solution should be sufficient. I was just wondering about some more pathological cases. I will wait a bit longer to see if something else shows up and if not I will accept your answer as that works fine for the examples I provided. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

If there is always 3 groups of characters and each group start's with a single letter and has 3 digits after that, and only the last group might have brackets, this expression might be just what you need:

```
w = 'w123 o456 (t789)'
clean = re.sub(r'^.*(\w\d{3})[ -]+(\w\d{3})[ -]+(\(?\w\d{3}\)?).*$', r'\1 \2 \3', w)
```

`clean` now prints `'w123 o456 (t789)'` even if there are some other characters at the beginning or end of string.

This expression look's for 3 groups of characters each consisting of a letter and 3 digits. For the last group there are optional brackets - `\(?` and `\)?`. All characters before and after the 3 groups are matched with `^.*` and `.*$`. Then we replace everything with just the 3 captured groups - `\1 \2 \3`

Comment: That does not work for `w='w123 -o456 t789-- --'`. Then the dashes still remain.

Comment: I updated my example. Tell mi if there are other character that might appear between groups so I can add them too.

Comment: That seems to work for the example, but usually I do not know the number of groups beforehand... Anyway, thanks for your efforts, I upvoted it as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Regex, why not use list comprehension (this auto keeps letters and digits if you don't want certain letters or digits we can change it too):

```
w = 'w123 o456 t789-- --'
list_to_keep =[' ']
print(''.join([x for x in w if x.isalnum() or x in list_to_keep]))
>> w123 o456 t789 

w = 'w123 o456 (t789)'
list_to_keep =[' '] # add to me
print(''.join([x for x in w if x.isalnum() or x in list_to_keep]))
>> w123 o456 t789
```

and for example:

```
w = 'w123 o456 (t789)'
list_to_keep =[' ', '('] # add to me (I added '(' to keep for example)
print(''.join([x for x in w if x.isalnum() or x in list_to_keep]))
>> w123 o456 (t789
```

and it works against what you edited saying Martin doesn't work:

```
w='w123 -o456 t789--) --'
list_to_keep =[' '] # add to me (I added '(' to keep for example)
print(''.join([x for x in w if x.isalnum() or x in list_to_keep]))
>> w123 o456 t789
```